# ZF2 routing not works properly

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 project based on the provided skeleton. I've made some controllers and actions using `ZFTool`. The problem is that router does not accepts URLs. It says: `The requested URL could not be matched by routing`

**Notes:**

1. The project is on an Apache Virtual Host
2. Controllers are created:

   ```
   $ zf.php  create controller user Application
   The controller user has been created in module Application.

   $zf.php  create action register user Application
   Creating action 'register' in controller 'Application\Controller\user'.
   Created view script at ./module/Application/view/application/user/register.phtml
   The action register has been created in controller Application\Controller\user.
   ```
3. And router have been configured like this:

   ```
   // ...
   'router' => array(
       'routes' => array(
           'home' => array(
               'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
               'options' => array(
                   'route'    => '/',
                   'defaults' => array(
                       'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                       'action'     => 'index',
                   ),
               ),
           ),
           // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
           // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
           // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
           // using the path /application/:controller/:action
           'application' => array(
               'type'    => 'Literal',
               'options' => array(
                   'route'    => '/application',
                   'defaults' => array(
                       '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                       'controller'    => 'Index',
                       'action'        => 'index',
                   ),
               ),
               'may_terminate' => true,
               'child_routes' => array(
                   'default' => array(
                       'type'    => 'Segment',
                       'options' => array(
                           'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                           'constraints' => array(
                               'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                               'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                           ),
                           'defaults' => array(
                           ),
                       ),
                   ),
               ),
           ),
       ),
   ),
   ```

Comment: Which uri do you try to access?

Comment: @BramGerritsen `www.mysite.local.com/user/register`. The entry is added to `/etc/hosts` and `www.mysite.local.com/` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segemented `controller/action` route is registered as a child route under `application`, this means you must type application in front: `www.mysite.local.com/application/user/register`.
If you don't want this you have to change your route definitions.

Comment: `<base>/application/user/register` does not work, but error message has changed: `The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class <new line> Application\Controller\User(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Application\Controller\User`. Funny fact: `<base>/application` and `<base>/application/index` work properly.

Comment: You need to register your controller at the controller manager. Eighter by using the controllers.invokables key in your module.config.php or by using the getControllerConfig() method in Module.php

Comment: Yes you can get rid of it. Just read up about and play with the router configuration. I prefer to just define all my routes and not use the magic `:controller/:action` route.

Comment: Can you show an example please? I'll be happy with manually added controllers, though can't find how to remove the magic. (tried a million combinations)

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/bramstroker/7831571. I have just moved the `:controller/:action` route as a child route under home and got rid of the application route.

Comment: well, I already tried it. Says: `user(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: user)`

Comment: You also need to define at which namespace your controller classes reside, see my updated gist.